# Booting initialization failure

Tags: boot

I'm using a desktop computer and it's old enough so that it suffers so many problems, but yesterday I shut it down correctly and now it can't even boot (I'm not talking about the OS like windows or linux but I'm talking about the computer's booting process before reaching the OS).
I'm using BIOS not UEFI and it's a dual one.
I'm sorry but I don't know what version the BIOS is.
My motherboard is Gigabyte P41T-D3P (2011).
Please, what to do ?????
Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking the following items:

- if you are getting BIOS screen just do hardware check. ( if anything fails means replace or try repairing that HW)
- Test the memory (you can download MemTest86 and burn it to a cd, then boot from that cd)
- Test the power supply (you can get a small hand-held tester, or if you have a known good supply maybe you can swap them)
- Check for bad capacitors on the motherboard (they will have tops that are bulging or have burst open)

  Thanks
  Santosh G.

Comment: Thanks Santosh Garole , I did a couple of web search moments and I concluded that BIOS is damaged (ROM is damaged) so I booted the computer and waited for more than 45 minutes,  then it worked , the BIOS was restored from a backup. Thanks again.